# How do I get L2TP to successfully install on Centos 5.9?

Tags: linux, vpn, centos, l2tp

I am trying to setup a Centos 5.9 VPS as a L2TP VPN server.

I am using this tutorial
[Tutorial](http://safesrv.net/setup-l2tpipsec-to-authenticate-off-freeradius-on-centos-5/) but when I try to start Racoon with `/etc/racoon/init.sh`

it gives me an error. `pfkey_open: Address family not supported by protocol`

I Googled the error and found: `modprobe af_key`

But this solution has an error also:

> FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.18-274.el5.028stab093.2/modules.dep: No such file or directory

I also downloaded the file "af_key.ko" manually and stored it in `/lib/modules/2.6.18-274.el5.028stab093.2/kernel`

then executed `modprobe af_key.ko`

but got the error `FATAL: Module af_key.ko not found`

then tried `depmod -a`

and then `lsmod`

but nothing is listed. I also tried  `insmod af_key.ko`

but got the error:

> insmod: error inserting 'af_key.ko': -1 Operation not permitted

I'm stuck at this step. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

System INFO:
Kernel Version: 2.6.18-274.el5.028stab093.2
OS: CentOS release 5.9 (Final)

Answer (score 1):

by the looks of it your using an OpenVZ based kernel - currently L2TP is not supported in that version of kernel, IPsec is supported inside containers since kernel 2.6.32.

Answer (score 0):

The /lib/modules folder is usually used for linux headers. Did you download your kernel's headers?

```
yum install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: tanks for ur time,
i used the command but it gives me the 
"No package linux-headers-2.6.18-274.el5.028stab093.2 available."
respond

Answer (score 0):

IPSec is only supported in kernel 2.6.32 and above. You are using 2.6.18. As it's an OpenVZ VPS, only your provider can update this (and probably won't).